# Flutter using launch url to open url in safari browser app got IOS App Rejected in app review for not implementing canopen()

Tags: ios, flutter, review, url-launcher

## I have used url_launcher: ^6.1.6 to open url in web browser in readers app but ios has rejected app stated this reasons in the mail :

Your "reader" app uses the External Link Account entitlement to link out for account creation and management but does not meet all requirements for using this entitlement.

Specifically, we found that your app does not meet the following requirement(s):

- Your app does not use the External Link Account API to populate the modal sheet before every instance of linking out for account creation and management.

[url for External Link Account entitlement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/external_link_account)

- Configure the SKExternalLinkAccount property list key.
- Use the ExternalLinkAccount type’s canOpen property and open() method.

**The link shows there is 2 things to implement first one we have done and second one is Use the ExternalLinkAccount type’s canOpen property and open() method I am not able to find this same thing in flutter in url launcher library can anyone help me how to implement canOpen and open() like iOS in flutter. I am sharing code of flutter were we open url
**

```
_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'https://www.bonusround.ca/signup';
  if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(url))) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url), mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

I want to know is their way to implement the ExternalLinkAccount type’s canOpen property and open() method in flutter as asked by Apple support to get approval for app.(note: code is working fine able to open url in iOS in browser)

Comment: You are using the wrong library. You will need to find a library or write native code that calls the appropriate methods on `ExternalLinkAccount`. Note that the `open()` method on this object does not accept a url; the system automatically selects one of the urls you configured in your property list.

Comment: @Paulw11 didn't found any other library need to go with other option. thanks